# equivalent ftp command for ftp rstatus on Solaris 10?

Tags: ftp, solaris

```
ftp rstatus $remotefile
```

is giving '`?Invalid command`' error on solaris. I came to know that there is no ftp command like `rstatus` on Solaris 10 unlike HP-UX. Basically on HP-UX, `rstatus` was used to get status of remote file. output like i.e.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 dearshady   users         20 Aug  2 10:28 remoteFile
```

On solaris ftp has `ls` command, but that is only for directory not file. Can anyone suggest a solution to get status of remote file on Solaris ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dir` instead of `rstatus`

```
ftp> rstatus z
?Invalid command
ftp> dir z
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root          34 mars 16 23:05 z
226 Transfer complete.
remote: z
58 bytes received in 0,00014 seconds (402,98 Kbytes/s)
```

Comment: Thanks. this is what I was looking for. One more thing, I am having similar issue with 'size'command. Could you let me know the equivalent for this too? thanks

Comment: There is no specific instruction to retrieve a file size. However you can easily get this information from the fifth column of the `dir` command output.

Comment: In HP-UX, "ftp> size remoteFile" gave the size in this format "213 391" where 391 being the file size. Now I want the same functionality in Solaris ftp. But there is no size command.

Comment: This size command looks to be HP-UX specific. You cannot extend ftp to support custom commands. You might use `curl --list-only` if curl is installed on your machine, but you'll still have to parse its output to extract the file size.